# Python: confusions with urljoin

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to form URLs from different pieces, and having trouble understanding the behavior of this method. For example:

**Python 3.x**

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

>>> urljoin('some', 'thing')
'thing'
>>> urljoin('http://some', 'thing')
'http://some/thing'
>>> urljoin('http://some/more', 'thing')
'http://some/thing'
>>> urljoin('http://some/more/', 'thing') # just a tad / after 'more'
'http://some/more/thing'
urljoin('http://some/more/', '/thing')
'http://some/thing'
```

Can you explain the exact behavior of this method?

Comment: Note to those coming across this question: the above import statement is for Python 3.x.  Use "from urlparse import urljoin" for python 2.x.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The best way (for me) to think of this is the first argument, `base` is like the page you are on in your browser.  The second argument `url` is the href of an anchor on that page.  The result is the final url to which you will be directed should you click.

```
>>> urljoin('some', 'thing')
'thing'
```

This one makes sense given my description.  Though one would hope base includes a scheme and domain.

```
>>> urljoin('http://some', 'thing')
'http://some/thing'
```

If you are on a vhost some, and there is an anchor like `<a href='thing'>Foo</a>` then the link will take you to `http://some/thing`

```
>>> urljoin('http://some/more', 'thing')
'http://some/thing'
```

We are on `some/more` here, so a relative link of `thing` will take us to `/some/thing`

```
>>> urljoin('http://some/more/', 'thing') # just a tad / after 'more'
'http://some/more/thing'
```

Here, we aren't on `some/more`, we are on `some/more/` which is different.  Now, our relative link will take us to `some/more/thing`

```
>>> urljoin('http://some/more/', '/thing')
'http://some/thing'
```

And lastly.  If on `some/more/` and the href is to `/thing`, you will be linked to `some/thing`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining... this kind of behaviour makes look for 'true' `urljoin`, acting similar to `os.path.join`

Comment: For those who also just want to add one bit of url onto another, without urljoin's logic, posixpath.join() may work for you.

Comment: I like `urljoin('http://', 'some/', 'thing')` how it ends up with: `'http:///some/'` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @seb urljoin is not variadic, the third parameter is a boolean flag

Comment: Thanks, I see. But still, the "///" is weird.

Answer (score 15):

> urllib.parse.urljoin(base, **url**)
>
> If url is an absolute URL (that is, starting with //, http://, https://, ...), the url’s host name and/or scheme will be present in the
>   result. For example:

```
>>> urljoin('https://www.google.com', '//www.microsoft.com')
'https://www.microsoft.com'
>>>
```

otherwise, urllib.parse.**urljoin**(base, url) will

> Construct a full (“absolute”) URL by combining a “base URL” (base) with another URL (url). Informally, this uses components of the base
>   URL, in particular the addressing scheme, the network location and
>   (part of) the path, to provide missing components in the relative URL.

```
>>> urlparse('http://a/b/c/d/e')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='a', path='/b/c/d/e', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urljoin('http://a/b/c/d/e', 'f')
>>>'http://a/b/c/d/f'
>>> urlparse('http://a/b/c/d/e/')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='a', path='/b/c/d/e/', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urljoin('http://a/b/c/d/e/', 'f')
'http://a/b/c/d/e/f'
>>>
```

it grabs the path of the first parameter (base), strips the part after the last / and joins with the second parameter (url).

If url starts with /, it joins the scheme and netloc of base with url

```
>>>urljoin('http://a/b/c/d/e', '/f')
'http://a/f'
```

Answer (score 3):

A picture is worth a thousand words.

```bash
$ python3
Python 3.11.4 (main, Jun 20 2023, 17:23:00) [Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> from urllib.parse import urljoin
>>> urljoin("http://a/b", "c/d")
'http://a/c/d'
>>> urljoin("http://a/b", "/c/d")
'http://a/c/d'
>>> urljoin("http://a/b/", "c/d")
'http://a/b/c/d'
>>> urljoin("http://a/b/", "/c/d")
'http://a/c/d'
```

**The best practice is**:

Use the "base" parameter with a trailing slash ("/"), and avoid starting the "url" parameter with a slash ("/").