# python's urlparse.urljoin removes path when concatenating

Tags: python, python-2.x, urlparse

Documentation of `urlparse.urljoin`, mentions that:
*"Informally, this uses components of the base URL, in particular the addressing scheme, the network location and **(part of) the path**"*

Thus I expect that:

```
urljoin('http://localhost:3000/foo', 'bar')
```

will give me:

```
http://localhost:3000/foo/bar
```

however I get:

```
http://localhost:3000/bar
```

I suppose that this is too common scenario to be a bug. Thus I expect that this is the normal behavior, and I was wondering: why? What do they mean "(part of) the path"? Isn't `foo` the actual path?

Comment: You should have a trailing slash on the 'foo' part.

Comment: possible dupe  --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/10893427/674039

Comment: yep it's a dupe. I am sorry I missed that. Although for python3 but the functionality is the same since it's about how a vhost path is defined. Thus we should close it I suppose