# python urljoin not finding the absolute path

Tags: python, html, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm trying to get the absolute path but I dont get the correct result. This is I'm trying:

Given I have this html page url:

```
url1 = 'build/en/index.html'
```

and I have this relative path in the file:

```
url2  = '/pub-assets/css/indexen.css'
```

I'm doing:

```
urljoin(url1, url2)
```

So I should get **build/pub-assets/css/indexen.css**

but I don't get what is expected.
Any suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893374/python-confusions-with-urljoin

Comment: @MdJohirulIslam I've already seen this post but it did not solve my issue

Comment: You are doing some other mistake. I run your code and get the correct path `https://example.com/en/pub-assets/css/indexen.css`. If you upload a little bit more code then that would help

Answer (score 0):

If your `url1` is a file (instead of directory), you should modify the path by using [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) and `ParseResult._replace` to modify the result.

```
from urlparse import urlsplit

url1 = 'https://example.com/en/index.html'
url2  = 'pub-assets/css/indexen.css'

p = urlsplit(url1).path
new_path = p[:p.rfind('/') + 1] + url2    #Gets the last directory and appends url
joined = urlsplit(url1)._replace(path=new_path)
print joined.geturl()  #Outputs https://example.com/en/pub-assets/css/indexen.css
```

This is assuming that `url1` is an absolute path and `url2` is a relative path.

Comment: url1 = 'build/en/index.html' --- url2  = '/pub-assets/css/indexen.css'  it results in: build/en//pub-assets/css/indexen.css

Comment: @Milix This was using your question as it was originally asked without the leading slash in `url2`. If you will always have a leading slash with `url2`, then drop the trailing slash by removing the `+1` in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.6.1:

```
>>> u1 = 'https://example.com/en/index.html'
>>> u2 = 'pub-assets/css/indexen.css'
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.urljoin(u1, u2)
'https://example.com/en/pub-assets/css/indexen.css'
```

Python 2.7.14:

```
>>> u1 = 'https://example.com/en/index.html'
>>> u2 = 'pub-assets/css/indexen.css'
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.urljoin(u1, u2)
'https://example.com/en/pub-assets/css/indexen.css'
```

Note the changed import. I would double-check your Python version, import statement, and perhaps post more of your program.

Comment: I'd encourage you to try parsing the urls using some more specific methods in [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html).

Comment: Also, using Python 3.6.4, I can `urljoin` your example URLs and I get `build/en/pub-assets/css/indexen.css`. What version of Python are you using?