# Python urljoin for html form url

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, urllib

i need to insert url path to my url from `html form` action parameter by using `urllib.parse.urljoin` but urljoin it does not work well in this example , for example 
url: `http://example.com/login/` 
form: `action="/test"` 
in web browser after click on submit button it will be like this `http://example.com/login/test` but in `urljoin` will be like this `http://example.com/test`

```py
>>> from urllib.parse import urljoin
>>> urljoin('http://example.com/login/','/test')
"http://example.com/test/"
```

my question about the url that got from action parameters for example : `action="/test"` in browser `http://example.com/login/test` in urllib `http://example.com/test` but if the value equal `action="/test/"` in browser and urllib `http://example.com/test/` , i need to make like browser when the value dose not end with `/`

any suggestion ?

thanks

Comment: There's a possible mistake in the question which makes it confusing. If you click a button in the browser with `/test`, you will get to `http://example.com/test` due to the leading slash. If the button has `./test` you will get to `http://example.com/login/test`. I just checked this both in the browser and in urljoin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `/` from the second parameter to `urljoin` gives the expected result i.e., `http://example.com/login/test`

```py
from urllib.parse import urljoin
base = 'http://example.com/login/'
path = '/test'
urljoin(base, path.strip('/'))
```

Note: urljoin should mimic the exact behaviour of browser. So if browser points to `http://example.com/login/test` then output of urljoin should too (and vice a versa). Are you sure about the expected result you want?

This question may provide more insights - [Python: confusions with urljoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893374/python-confusions-with-urljoin)