# FastAPI - adding route prefix to TestClient

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

I have a FastAPI app with a route prefix as `/api/v1`.

When I run the test it throws `404`. I see this is because the `TestClient` is not able to find the route at `/ping`, and works perfectly when the route in the test case is changed to `/api/v1/ping`.

Is there a way in which I can avoid changing all the routes in all the test functions as per the prefix? This seems to be cumbersome as there are many test cases, and also because I dont want to have a hard-coded dependency of the route prefix in my test cases. Is there a way in which I can configure the prefix in the `TestClient` just as we did in `app`, and simply mention the route just as mentioned in the `routes.py`?

**routes.py**

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter

router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/ping")
async def ping_check():
    return {"msg": "pong"}
```

**main.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from routes import router

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(prefix="/api/v1")
```

In the test file I have:

**test.py**

```py
from main import app
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

client = TestClient(app)

def test_ping():
    response = client.get("/ping")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"msg": "pong"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out a workaround for this.

The `TestClient` has an option to accept a `base_url`, which is then `urljoin`ed with the route `path`. So I appended the route prefix to this `base_url`.

> [source](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/84e2dc7bfe35aa82a0db958519810309e73de8f5/starlette/testclient.py#L467):
>
> `url = urljoin(self.base_url, url)`

**However, there is a catch to this** - `urljoin` concatenates as expected only when the `base_url` ends with a `/` and the `path` does not start with a `/`. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10893427/4260095) explains it well.

This resulted in the below change:

**test.py**

```py
from main import app, ROUTE_PREFIX
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

client = TestClient(app)
client.base_url += ROUTE_PREFIX  # adding prefix
client.base_url = client.base_url.rstrip("/") + "/"  # making sure we have 1 and only 1 `/`

def test_ping():
    response = client.get("ping")  # notice the path no more begins with a `/`
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"msg": "pong"}
```

Answer (score 3):

Had to cast @Shod's answer to str for it to work on FastAPI 0.104

```
client = TestClient(app)
client.base_url = str(client.base_url) + settings.api_prefix  # adding prefix
client.base_url = str(client.base_url).rstrip("/") + "/"  # making sure we have 1 and only 1 `/`
```

Answer (score 1):

The above work-around (by Shod) worked for me, but I had to pass the APIRouter object instead of FastAPI object to the testclient. I was receiving a 404 error otherwise.
Below is a sample code for how it worked for me.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

app = FastAPI()
router = APIRouter(prefix="/sample")

app.include_router(router)

@router.post("/s1")
def read_main():
    return {"msg": "Hello World"}

client = TestClient(router)
client.base_url += "/sample"
client.base_url = client.base_url.rstrip("/") + "/"

def test_main():
    response = client.post("s1")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"msg": "Hello World"}
```