# Using urljoin to add query-parameter value

Tags: python, urllib

I have a prepared URL `https://my.comp.com/Online/SendToken?token=`  that I want to append the parameter value `123` to.

What I have tried so far:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

urljoin('https://my.comp.com/Online/SendToken?token=','123')
# prints 'https://my.comp.com/Online/123'
```

What I want to get is:

```
'https://my.comp.com/Online/SendToken?token=123'
```

I know I can use `+` to concatenate two strings, but I want to use the `urljoin` for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue

If you only pass a query-parameter value, it will not join them as expected.

### Second argument

The second argument is interpreted as path, so it needs to be a valid

- complete path,
- path segment (may include query-parameter or fragment)
- query (prefixed with `?`
- fragment (prefixed with `#`)

See the [docs for `urljoin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin), use the first 2 examples:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

# the complete query-parameter (question-mark, key, value)
urljoin('https://my.comp.com/Online/SendToken?token=','?token=123')
# 'https://my.comp.com/Online/SendToken?token=123'

# the complete path-segment including query
urljoin('https://my.comp.com/Online/SendToken?token=','SendToken?token=123')
# 'https://my.comp.com/Online/SendToken?token=123'

# a fragment (denoted by hash-symbol) will also work, but not desired
urljoin('https://my.comp.com/Online/SendToken?token=','#123')
# 'https://my.comp.com/Online/SendToken?token=#123'
```

See also [Python: confusions with urljoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893374/python-confusions-with-urljoin)